# Address of host you connect from

Tags: ssh

When you connect to some remote machine using ssh, is there an easy way to **address of the machine you connecting from** ? (with some env variable, or hostname for instance)

Main use how that would be to scp/transfer file back where you connect from, without having to disconnect.

*(Might be a possible duplicate, didn't realy how to well formulate the question)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an extension of Bruce's answer, you can get *only* the originating IP address (instead of a string containing the IP address, the source port, and the destination port) by doing this:

```
echo "${SSH_CLIENT%% *}"
```

This works by stripping everything from the first space onwards, leaving you with only the originating IP.

Answer (score 2):

If you have logged in via `ssh`, the environment variable `SSH_CLIENT` has the "from machine's" IP address in it.

If you have logged in via some other method (you should NOT be logging in via `telnet`), the `who` and `w` commands tell you where you came from.